# How can I set up multiple hgweb sites on one IIS server?

Tags: windows, iis, mercurial, hgweb

I'm setting up our company's first Mercurial web interface, and I've hit a bit of a roadblock.  We will have multiple teams using this server, and I don't want team A to have to deal with team B's repositories, and vice-versa.

If hgweb served the repositories as they were held in the folder tree, that would be perfect.  Unfortunately, all of the templates I've seen "flatten the tree" into a simple repository list. So I've been trying to set up multiple sites, so that https://hg.server/teamA lists only team A's repos, and https://hg.server/teamB shows only team B's repos.  Sounds simple enough!

I'm using ISAPI rather than CGI. Unfortunately, the ISAPI handler seems incapable of pointing to more than one hgweb.config file.

I'm impressed with RhodeCode's look, but I have been unable to get it installed properly. I'm extremely new to Python; so some of the installation instructions are, to say the least, confusing.

So... any suggestions on how to successfully install RhodeCode, or otherwise do what I need to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that `hgweb` will descend into subdirectories by default and show everything in a big flat list. But try setting

```
[web]
descend = False
```

to prevent this. You can still browse the subdirectories directly, as shown in this example on my server:

- http://hg.lazybytes.net/team-a/
- http://hg.lazybytes.net/team-b/

The top-level directory will then look pretty empty, though. Leaving `web.descend` at its default values might then be better — you'll then see a big flat list at the top-level, but can still **browse subdirectories** to only see the repos specific to each team. Seems like the best of both worlds.